# sed: Remove value and insert at the end

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have following Strings

```
"1 Michael"
"2 John" ...
```

and I´d like to transform them into

```
"Michael 1"
"John 2" ....
```

How can I do this?

The Strings are stored in one shell variable and each string represents a seperate line.

So when calling echo "$var" it prints

```
1 Michael
2 John
```

Comment: Where are the strings? Are they in a file? One per line? Are they in shell variables? A shell array? Two separate shell variables? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also, what operating system are you using? Different systems have different `sed` implementations with different capabilities.

Comment: Thank you! Somebody just posted a solutions and it worked: echo "$string" | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+) (.*)/\2 \1/'

Comment: Great! Please remember to [accept the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) (it has been undeleted).

Comment: What prevents you from just doing `var='Michael 1 John 2'`? I mean, it might sound daft, but not knowing what created the string in the first place, this is as good a solution as any. If we knew where the string came from and how it was produced, _that_ may possibly be changed rather than doing a post-processing step.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have a huge file with this type of strings, so I just read the file

Comment: @Justin You see, that's quite a different problem. In that case, you don't even have to read the line into a variable. So this is, I presume, just an exercise in reordering columns in a file, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, this was just for training! Next time I will form the question better, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "$string" | sed -E 's/([[:digit:]]+) (.*)/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: I undeleted this, Glenn, since it seems to be precisely what the OP was after.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment here. It was clearly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the two whitespace-delimited fields with `awk`:

```bash
awk '{ print $2, $1 }' file >outfile
```

The output is written as a space-delimited file to the file called `outfile`.

Testing:

```bash
$ cat file
1 Michael
2 John
```

```bash
$ awk '{ print $2, $1 }' file >outfile
```

```bash
$ cat outfile
Michael 1
John 2
```

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about changing the order of the lines, does it?

Comment: @DonHolgo :-) No it doesn't. I honestly don't know where I got that from. The question originally was not properly marked up and I might have read it wrongly due to that. I'll update and fix it. Thanks for the heads up!